# What is the 'relauncher' entry in my Privacy & Security panel referring to

Tags: macos

I see these entries appearing in the panel Unselected but no idea what they refer to?
Anyone?

[image]

Comment: What 3rd party apps do you have installed?  It's a rather generic name for an app re-launcher so it's tough to guess it's associate with just that name:  "Relauncher". It looks like you may have installed this app several times and not given permission to the Relauncher application to run.

Comment: If you right click on each Relauncher entry, and select "Show in Finder", what does it show? Where are they located?